# What do I use for URL when using AJAX to connect to server side PHP

Tags: javascript, php, server-side

I don't know what to use as the URL variable when setting up AJAX to send a post to server side PHP

I am hosting a website with Apache (latest version) on CentOS 7. I have PHP waiting for a post on the server side and an AJAX connection on the client side (with JavaScript). when calling the AJAX I can't figure out what to use for the URL parameter (I have tried the file name and IP
address)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(query),
    }
```

I expected the POST to go through and return the necessary data but instead nothing happens

Comment: does `search.php` exist in the same folder on the server as the current document? then that should work - you'll need to add a lot more detail to your setup if not

Answer (score 0):

To `url` name of PHP file which has to serve Ajax request on server.

In PHP script you here get sent data in raw input. Better for you can be remove `JSON.stringify(query)` and put `query` directly, because that was filled to `$_POST` variable on PHP side.

Comment: thanks! i checked and along with your advice and Re-Configuring Apache i got everything working perfectly.